# mysql error : not accessible as a command

Tags: mysql, ubuntu-12.04, lampp

```
root@vps:~# /opt/lampp/lampp startmysql
XAMPP: Starting MySQL...already running.
root@vps:~# mysql
-bash: mysql: command not found
```

I have installed **XAMPP/LAMPP** on **my ubuntu 12.04 server**. 
MySQL is running but when I type mysql in command it says **command not found**.
Now, how should i access mysql

[image]

When i tried this :

```
root@vps:/bin# cd /opt/lampp/bin
root@vps:/opt/lampp/bin# ./mysql
Welcome to the MySQL monitor.  Commands end with ; or \g.
Your MySQL connection id is 1
Server version: 5.6.24 Source distribution

Copyright (c) 2000, 2015, Oracle and/or its affiliates. All rights reserved.

Oracle is a registered trademark of Oracle Corporation and/or its
affiliates. Other names may be trademarks of their respective
owners.

Type 'help;' or '\h' for help. Type '\c' to clear the current input statement.

mysql>
```

it is working.
Why cannot i access it directly by typing **mysql** at **command**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Run these commands on terminal:

```
 cd /bin
 ln  /opt/lampp/bin/mysql mysql
 mysql
```

Now **mysql** has become a legal command on your system. you will get something like this :

```
root@vps:/# mysql
Welcome to the MySQL monitor.  Commands end with ; or \g.
Your MySQL connection id is 4
Server version: 5.6.24 Source distribution

Copyright (c) 2000, 2015, Oracle and/or its affiliates. All rights reserved.

Oracle is a registered trademark of Oracle Corporation and/or its
affiliates. Other names may be trademarks of their respective
owners.

Type 'help;' or '\h' for help. Type '\c' to clear the current input statement.

mysql>
```

Answer (score 0):

**Try this one**

> cd /opt/lampp/bin
>
> ./mysql

OR

first goto the bin directory where mysql is installed.
then try

> ./mysql

Comment: -bash: cd: /opt/lampp/lampp: Not a directory

Comment: first goto the bin directory where you find executable of mysql. then just try 
./mysql

Comment: root@vps:/bin# ./mysql
-bash: ./mysql: No such file or directory

Comment: try 
cd /opt/lampp/bin